# Запретить запуск таймера после обновления страницы

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет, есть простенький js викторины. 3 варианта ответа и при окончании времени перекидывает на страницу соответственно выбранному ответу.

```js
function timer() {
  var obj = document.getElementById("timer_inp");
  obj.innerHTML--;
  if (obj.innerHTML == 0) {
    stopTest();
    setTimeout(function() {}, 1000);
  } else {
    setTimeout(timer, 1000);
  }
}
setTimeout(timer, 1000);

function stopTest() {
  if (document.getElementById("1").checked) {
    location.href = "a1.html";
  } else {
    if (document.getElementById("2").checked) {
      location.href = "a2.html";
    } else {
      location.href = "a3.html";
    }
  }
}
```

Но можно обойти скрипт, просто нажав кнопку назад после того как закончится время и обновить страницу, таймер запустится заново, а правильный вариант ответа уже будет известен.

Вопрос: как запретить повторный запуск скрипта после обновления страницы?

Comment: нет смысла делать викторину на js, так как любой пользователь может посмотреть исходный код

Comment: Если скрипт будет лежать в папке js, то как пользователь туда попадет?
Он может видеть только html-код, разве не так?=)

Comment: очень просто) F12 на клавиатуре

Comment: JavaScript работает на стороне пользователя (тоесть у пользователя есть полный доступ к скриптам, картинкам, хтмл)

Comment: Викторина на голом js - норм штука, но если речь зашла о "безопасности", то действительно первым делом нужно переложить логику на бекенд.

Comment: Ну, на ответ дается 10 секунд, так что времени на просмотр и скачивание файла не будет. А вот вопрос с повторным запуском скрипта после обновления страницы стоит остро=(

Comment: Я вижу только один способ: когда пользователь закончит проходить тест создать переменную в localStorage, наявнось которой мы будем проверять если пользователь захочет вернутся назад. Но это костыль, и спользовать это не профитно, если делать тесты то проверять на сервере.

Comment: куки в помощь или локалстрендж